# Adding section numbering to boxed environment

Tags: numbering, environments, mdframed, amsthm, newtheorem

I have the following boxed environment in with I would like to add section numbering. It should say "Bevis #.#" instead of just "Bevis".

Image of what I currently have
[image: Help]

The code I'm using

```
\documentclass{report}  
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}  
\usepackage{lipsum}  

\newtheoremstyle{bev}  
  {\topsep}%  
  {\topsep}%  
  {\normalfont}%  
  {}%  
  {\bfseries}%  
  {:}%  
  {.5em}%  
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnote{~(#3)}}%  
\theoremstyle{bev}  
\newmdtheoremenv[  
hidealllines=true,  
innertopmargin=0pt,  
linewidth=4pt,  
linecolor=gray!40,  
singleextra={  
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O|-P) -- +(1cm,0pt);  
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O|-P) -- +(0pt,-1cm);  
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O-|P) -- +(-1cm,0pt);  
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O-|P) -- +(0pt,1cm);  
  },  
firstextra={  
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O|-P) -- +(1cm,0pt);  
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O|-P) -- +(0pt,-1cm);  
},  
secondextra={  
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O-|P) -- +(-1cm,0pt);  
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O-|P) -- +(0pt,1cm);  
}  
]{bev}{Bevis}  

\begin{document}  

\begin{bev}  
\lipsum[4]  
\end{bev}  

\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  The final argument of `\theoremstyle` should either be left empty, to get a default, or include the `\thmnumber{#2}` specification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mdframed` package and its `\newmdframedtheoremenv` command work basically like `\newtheorem`, it is possible add a resetting counter, which is `section` here (as requested).

However, using `chapters` the usual `\thesection` command will have `\thechapter.\arabic{section}`, so the `\thebev` command should be redefined to be `\arabic{section}.\arabic{bev}`.

To see the number at all, use `\thmnumber{#2}` in the definition of the theorem style (it's the last argument of `\newtheoremstyle`)

```
\documentclass{report}  
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}  
\usepackage{lipsum}  


\newtheoremstyle{bev}  
  {\topsep}%  
  {\topsep}%  
  {\normalfont}%  
  {}%  
  {\bfseries}%  
  {:}%  
  {.5em}%  
  {\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2}\thmnote{~(#3)}}%  
\theoremstyle{bev}  
\newmdtheoremenv[  
hidealllines=true,  
innertopmargin=0pt,  
linewidth=4pt,  
linecolor=gray!40,  
singleextra={  
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O|-P) -- +(1cm,0pt);  
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O|-P) -- +(0pt,-1cm);  
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O-|P) -- +(-1cm,0pt);  
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O-|P) -- +(0pt,1cm);  
  },  
firstextra={  
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O|-P) -- +(1cm,0pt);  
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O|-P) -- +(0pt,-1cm);  
},  
secondextra={  
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O-|P) -- +(-1cm,0pt);  
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O-|P) -- +(0pt,1cm);  
}  
]{bev}{Bevis}[section]

\renewcommand{\thebev}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{bev}}

\begin{document}  

\chapter{Foo chapter}
\section{Foo 1}
\begin{bev}  
\lipsum[4]  
\end{bev}  

\section{Foo 2}
\begin{bev}  
\lipsum[4]  
\end{bev}  


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new counter `\newcounter{bevCounter}`. Set counter increment with `\refstepcounter{bevCounter}`. The counter value gives `\thebevCounter`.

With adding `\usepackage{amsmath}`    you can use `\numberwithin{bevCounter}{section}` to define section numbering.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}  
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}  
\usepackage{lipsum}  


\newcounter{bevCounter} 

\newtheoremstyle{bev}  
  {\topsep}%  
  {\topsep}%  
  {\normalfont}%  
  {}%  
  {\bfseries}%  
  {:}%  
  {.5em}%  
  {\thmname{#1}\thmnote{~(#3)}}%  
\theoremstyle{bev}  
\newmdtheoremenv[  
hidealllines=true,  
innertopmargin=0pt,  
linewidth=4pt,  
linecolor=gray!40,  
singleextra={  
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O|-P) -- +(1cm,0pt);  
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O|-P) -- +(0pt,-1cm);  
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O-|P) -- +(-1cm,0pt);  
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O-|P) -- +(0pt,1cm);  
  },  
firstextra={  
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O|-P) -- +(1cm,0pt);  
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O|-P) -- +(0pt,-1cm);  
},  
secondextra={  
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O-|P) -- +(-1cm,0pt);  
  \draw[line width=3pt,gray!50,line cap=rect] (O-|P) -- +(0pt,1cm);  
}  
]{bev}{Bevis \refstepcounter{bevCounter} \thebevCounter}  

\usepackage{amsmath}
\numberwithin{bevCounter}{section}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}

\section{sec 1}
\begin{bev}  
\lipsum[4]  
\end{bev}  

\begin{bev}  
\lipsum[4]  
\end{bev}  

\section{Two}
\begin{bev}  
\lipsum[4]  
\end{bev}  


\end{document}
```